# NixOS: Screen connected over USB-C stays black

Tags: usb, xrandr, x-server, intel-graphics, nixos

I've got a Dell XPS 13' (9350), with a Dell USB-C to HDMI adapter, connected to a screen. I'm running NixOS with XMonad. The screen (set to HDMI input) shows "no input signal" despite:

- `xrandr` showing the screen as "connected", with expected resolution ([`xrandr`](http://hastebin.com/akelulojov.txt))
- kernel version `4.4.8` should support Skylake processor ([`uname -a`](http://hastebin.com/cumuxuciti.txt))
- `lsmod` shows `i915` as being loaded ([`lsmod | grep i915`](http://hastebin.com/biwiluseha.txt))
- screenshots show the second screen, including windows

I don't think the second screen shows up in [`lshw`](http://hastebin.com/cunowejome.txt), but then how can `xrandr` see it? I'm not sure where to look next. I hope anyone here does.

EDIT: I just found out that a VGA cable connected to the same adapter *does* work.

Comment: Similar issue, but with Windows: https://superuser.com/questions/821441/second-screen-detected-but-completely-blank-in-windows-8-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I purchased a second USB-C to HDMI adapter, and everything works perfectly with it. Conclusion: The first adapter I had is broken.